# React, How do I detect the misspelling of lifecycle method name in a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

sometimes, my colleague misspell the `react` component lifecycle method name. like this:

```
...
componentWillReceveProps() {} //misspell
...
```

but, `react` will not throw an error, `webpack` either.

so, is there a `tool` to solve my question? Thanks.

Comment: what editor do you use?

Comment: vscode. Is there a `tool` like `eslint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [typescript interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) to enforce the correct method name. Here are some tutorials on working with typescript and react:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html
http://blog.wolksoftware.com/working-with-react-and-typescript

I don't have experience with this combination but it might help you. Of course your component has to implement the correct interface and your colleague might still forget to do that.

Comment: I don't want to use `ts`. Is there a `tool` like `eslint`?